# How to dynamically nest 3 iOS tables/sections into one?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm looking to create a UITableView containing 3 sections (Each section just displaying a centered UILabel), within each section there is to be a dynamic number of cells. The first of the cells (MainCell) will have an image view and a label, and the final number of dynamic cells (DetailCell) will have information based on the MainCell. The only information that is fixed is that there are 3 sections. Anybody have any idea as to what to do? I could split them into 3 tables but would rather them all be in one if possible. I've tried playing around with grouped tables but then I'm not sure on how to have a varying number of DetailCells for each MainCell.

I've attached an image which should hopefully help explain what I'm trying to do.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

[image: Nested table]

Comment: What about create dictionary with the size of 3, each key in the dictionary will contain array of models and each model will contains all the fields which are relevant for your cell with additional property of type that will contain the row type if it is main or detail. in number of rows for section you simply get the array inside the dictionary section and return the count of this array

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know about your data source, you could do something like this:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell?

        if indexPath.row % 3 == 0
        {
            // this is a "MainCell"
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        }
        else
        {
            // this is a "DetailCell"
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        }

        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("HeaderCell")

        return cell
    }
}
```

The storyboard would have multiple cell types represented:

[image: Storyboard]

The result is this:

[image: App running]